# Selenium: select overlay input type file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having some problems with Selenium.
I have this overlay `div`, which contains an input type file and I'm trying to select it:

```
<div class="xenOverlay attachmentUploader"
    style="z-index: 9999; top: 92.7px; left: 206px; position: fixed; display: block;">

    <form action="http://localhost/xenforo/index.php?attachments/do-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        class="formOverlay AutoInlineUploader AttachmentUploadForm NoAutoHeader" data-overlayclass="attachmentUploader">

        <dl class="ctrlUnit">
            <dt><label for="ctrl_upload">Upload a File (<span title="1,048,576 bytes">Max 1 MB</span>):</label></dt>
            <dd id="SWFUploadContainer" data-placeholder="#SWFUploadPlaceHolder" data-trigger="#ctrl_upload">
                <span id="SWFUploadPlaceHolder"></span>
                <input type="file" name="upload" class="textCtrl" onchange="this.blur()" id="ctrl_upload">
                <input type="reset" value="Close" class="OverlayCloser button smallButton">
            </dd>
        </dl>

        <div class="attachmentConstraints pairsRows">
            <dl>
                <dt>Accepted file types:</dt>
                <dd>zip, txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, jpe, gif, torrent</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="_xfToken" value="1,1482434233,ccadf23a674c4c4b9def910cf5d55cea4b44ab2a">
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="a9288bd75c0c87638d9057237511e16c">
        <input type="hidden" name="content_type" value="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="content_data[node_id]" value="3">
    </form>
</div>
```

I've tried selecting the input type file by `id` and by `xpath` but eclipse only gives me errors.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctrl_upload']"));
elem.sendKeys("C://e.txt");
```

I'm using Selenium 3.0.1 with ChromeDriver on Windows 10

**UPDATE:**

Full code:

```
static void createNewThread(WebDriver driver, String category, String title, String message){       
    String url = "http://localhost/xenforo/index.php?forums/" + category + "/create-thread";
    driver.get(url);

    WebElement ttl = driver.findElement(By.className("titleBOT"));
    ttl.clear();
    ttl.sendKeys(title);

    WebElement msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ThreadCreate']/fieldset[1]/dl[2]/dd/div/div/iframe"));
    msg.click();
    msg.clear();
    msg.sendKeys(message); 

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctrl_uploader']")).click();   

    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
    elem.sendKeys("C:\\e.txt");

    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ThreadCreate']/dl[2]/dd/input[1]")).click();    
}
```

I think it doesn't finds the element that I'm searching. This element appears only when I click a button, and overlays the old content.

**UPDATE 2:**

I think I've found the problem. The Upload is via flash, not via html, when I click the flash button via `click()` the website doesn't reacts the same as with a real user click.

Comment: I am little bit confuse, what `WebElement msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ThreadCreate']/fieldset[1]/dl[2]/dd/div/div/iframe"));` this doing. Are clicking on a iFrame and then clear and then sending some text. I have few guidelines - 1. You can enter and clear values only of textfields. 2. If there is frame in your page then first you need to switch to that frame and then have to locate element under it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
elem.sendKeys("C://e.txt");
```

Let me know, whether it works.

Comment: Doesn't works, eclipse keeps giving me a bunch of errors on the `WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));` 's line when i try to run the script.

Comment: Could you please share the error or exception trace?

Comment: Additionally, is this control appears under **div** with class **xenOverlay attachmentUploader**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way Hope it will work-

`driver.findElement(By.id("ctrl_upload")).sendKeys("C:\\e.txt");`

and do correct your file path `C://e.txt` to `C:\\e.txt`

Comment: plz provide some code snippet what actually you are doing . In your error log it seems your are doing clear a non editable textbox